# React: How to refresh the list on form submit without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying the data  in the list with sort order in the textbox. User can change the order and click on submit will save the changed order in the database. list will be displaying in the new order on page refresh.
Issue: How to refresh the list on form submit Without Page Refresh. Please help. Please find my sandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-morning-k4emln

```
import React from "react";
import XMLParser from "react-xml-parser";
const data = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Category>
<description description-id="11" display-sequence="2">testing</description>
<description description-id="15" display-sequence="5">Guide</description>
<description description-id="20" display-sequence="7">test</description>
<description description-id="25" display-sequence="10">Guide</description>
<description description-id="30" display-sequence="12">test</description>
</Category>
</xml>`;
const REQUEST_URL = "";
const axios = {
 get: () =>
   new Promise((resolve) => {
     setTimeout(resolve, 1000, { data });
   })
};
class Order_Descriptions extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     proddescriptions: [],
     proddescription_id: "",
     display_sequence: ""
   };
 }

 handleChange = (event) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   this.setState((prevState) => ({
     proddescriptions: prevState.proddescriptions.map((el) =>
       el.id === name
         ? {
             ...el,
             sequence: value
           }
         : el
     )
   }));
 };

 componentDidMount() {
   this.getlistofdescriptions();
 }

 getlistofdescriptions() {
   axios
     .get(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
     .then((response) => {
       const jsonDataFromXml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data);
       const descriptions = jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName(
         "description"
       );
       /*  console.log(descriptions);
         this.setState({
           proddescriptions: jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName("description")
         });
       });
            const URL = "/descriptionlist"
             axios
                   .get(URL, { 'withCredentials': 'true' })
                                .then((response) => {
             const jsonDataFromXml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(response.data);
             const descriptions = jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName(
"description" )*/
       const proddescriptions = descriptions.map(({ attributes, value }) => ({
         id: attributes["description-id"],
         sequence: attributes["display-sequence"],
         value
       }));
       this.setState({
         proddescriptions
       });
     });
 }
 handleSubmit = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   const ProdDescriptions = this.state.proddescriptions;
   const URL = "/descriptionlist/order";
   const data = {
     ProdDescriptions
   };

   fetch(URL, {
     method: "POST",
     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
     credentials: "include",
     body: JSON.stringify(data)
   })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((data) => {
       this.setState({
         ValidationStatus: data
       });
     })
     .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
 };

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <div>
           <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
             {this.state.proddescriptions.map((item) => (
               <li key={item.id}>
                 <label>
                   <input
                     type="text"
                     name={item.id}
                     size="5"
                     maxLength="3"
                     value={item.sequence}
                     onChange={this.handleChange}
                   />
                 </label>
                 &nbsp;{item.value}{" "}
               </li>
             ))}
           </ul>
         </div>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="btnsubmit" />
       </form>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
export default function App() {
 return (
   <div className="App">
     <h1>Sort Data</h1>
     <h5>Submit button sort list without page refresh</h5>
     <Order_Descriptions />
   </div>
 );
}
```

thanks

Comment: Is it possible to send the data back on success of submission API ? in that way you can set the data to state from the response back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort proddescriptions state  on fetch success

here is what I did

First, I add compare function to use it in sort function

```
compare(a, b) {
  if (parseInt(a.sequence, 10) > parseInt(b.sequence, 10)) return 1;
  if (parseInt(a.sequence, 10) < parseInt(b.sequence, 10)) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

and then sort proddescriptions state in fetch success:

```
    this.setState({ proddescriptions: ProdDescriptions.sort(compare) });
```

here you can see the result :

https://codesandbox.io/s/late-tdd-rnzr6e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks Ali for the solution. it works.

Comment: Hi Ali, Is there a way to do sorting alphabetically?

Comment: Hi, you mean you wanna sort it by item.value?

Comment: sort it by the sequence(order). if the order is same, then sort it by item.value

Comment: aha, you can add another compare,
let me edit codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-tdd-rnzr6e?file=/src/App.js
check this out

Comment: Thanks Ali. Currently, its not working.

Comment: Hi Ali, please check the code. data is not sorted on page submit now.

Comment: Hi, you mean it does not compare arrays to sort or it's not sorting at all ?

Comment: Yes, its not sorting at all.

Comment: Hi Ali, code in the sandbox is not sorting anymore on form submit without page refresh.

Comment: Hi, could you please send me response sample from backend?

Comment: Backend sample looks like {[
  {
    "id": "2126", "sequence": "1","value": "First Test"
  },
  {
    "id": "2123","sequence": "3", "value": "Test edit Happy Halloween"
  },
  {
    "id": "2125", "sequence": "3","value": "test new test testing testing edit"
  },
  {
    "id": "2112","sequence": "3","value": "This is testtesttt"
  },
  {
    "id": "2124","sequence": "9","value": "Testing add again."
  },

]}

Comment: Sort data with sequence and item value on form submit without page refresh.  Data was initially sorted fine with sequence.

Comment: Hi Ali, your initial code works fine with sequence. list was sorted properly. The new code is not working in which it first sort with sequence, if sequence is same, then it will sort with title.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `this.getlistofdescriptions()` when the post request succeed (the place where you set the validation status after the request).

Comment: Please update my code what needs to be done.